# Problems with afterAll() in ScalaTest in case of Future usage

Tags: scala, scalatest

At the end of my ScalaTest suite I need to do some DB clean up.
The cleanup itself is a `Future`. The suite does not call the `super.afterAll()` which leaves some resources used by the suite (like a web browser and db connections) pending.

Here is relevant pieces of code:

```
override def afterAll():Unit={
    var cleanUpsInProgress = true
    DB.cleanUpDeletedSegments(db).onComplete{case _ =>
      cleanUpsInProgress = false
    }
    while(cleanUpsInProgress){}
    db.close()
    aggregatesDB.close()
    super.afterAll()
  }
```

and

```
def cleanUpDeletedSegments(implicit db:ADMPDB):Future[Int]={
  db.run{
    segments.filter(_.deleted === 1).delete
  }
}
```

I've debugged and scratched my head for a while and got to conclusion it is not even processing the code in the future's `onComplete` callback. Even when I substitute Slick's db action with stub `Future.successfull(1)` I still have everything pending and `super.afterAll()` gets NOT invoked.
Probably I'm doing something stupidly wrong? Could you help?

Note: Also I do think I need to use this ugly `var` and `while` loop here because otherwise the main thread gets completed and the framework which initiates the suite running just closes JVM. Maybe I am wrong here so would be great to hear some comments.

--------------------------UPDATE----------------------

The solution by Tyler works. But when I `flatMap` one more asynch cleanup (which I actually need to do) then the problem is the same again. The code below freezes and does not call `super.afterAll`:

```
override def afterAll():Unit={
  val cleanUp = DB.cleanUpDeletedSegments(db).flatMap(_ => DB.cleanUpDeletedSegmentGroups(db))
  Await.result(cleanUp, 6 seconds)
  db.close()
  aggregatesDB.close()
  super.afterAll()
}
```

`Await.result` also does not throw TimeoutException and from what I see neither completed normally. Any ideas?

It works only if I use `Await.result` sequentially for each future like below:

```
override def afterAll():Unit={
  val cleanUpSegments = DB.cleanUpDeletedSegments(db)
  Await.result(cleanUpSegments, 3 seconds)
  val cleanUpSegmentGroups = DB.cleanUpDeletedSegmentGroups(db)
  Await.result(cleanUpSegmentGroups, 3 seconds)
  db.close()
  aggregatesDB.close()
  super.afterAll()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its probably just easier to `await` for your `Future` cleanup to finish:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

override def afterAll() ={
  val future = DB.cleanUpDeletedSegments(db)
  Await.result(future, 2 minutes)
  aggregatesDB.close()
  super.afterAll()
}
```

You can set the timeout to whatever is reasonable

Comment: your solution works partially. I've updated the question. Could you review and share your thoughts?

Comment: If I do not `flatMap` that other future then everything works as expected. The second future is pretty much the same, just cleans up another db table, so I don't think there are some peculiarities there.

Comment: It works if for each future I use `Await.result` sequentially. Really strange. I've updated the question accordingly, probably other guys will have some explanation for it.

Comment: You do not want to use `Await` in production code but in tests it is completely fine, and usually makes things easier to reason about.  Having multiple `Awaits` is fine.

Comment: I would argue here that certain test code is not less important than the production code. But that's not the main point. Would be really interesting to understand why standard `Future` combinators produce such result.

Comment: `Await` can cause a deadlock if you call `await` (http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/01/fun-with-pool-induced-deadlock.html). You can check thread dump (in IDE, for example) and see if it is this case. Await shouldn't be called in the thread which belongs to execution context that runs futures.

Answer (score 2):

Use solution by @Tyler. Your solution didn't work because you used non-volatile variable `cleanupInProgress` from multiple threads.

Comment: are there ways to achieve the result without blocking `Await.result` ? Just for educational purposes, would be good to know how to code such things in a "nice" way.

Comment: `Await` is considered not-nice not because it waits wrong way. The idea of waiting for something is bad itself (mostly). But in your case of test it is fine.

Comment: by the way, having `@volatile var cleanUpsInProgress = true` does not make any difference

Comment: Try to insert `Thread.sleep (100)` inside `while` cycle. Otherwise I'll check on Monday.